# Writing to TXT using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I am attempting to parse text entered within a HTML file. My code should call a PHP script to output the fields entered into a .txt located on the server. I've made sure to give CHMOD permissions of 777 to the .txt on the webserver, however nothing is being appended to this file after I click Submit. Any help will be greatly appreciated, apologies for the bad syntax and form.

### HTML FORM CODE:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<tr><td align="right">Name:</td><td><input name="auth_name" type="text" style="border: 1px dashed;"></td></tr>
                                                                                    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                                                                       <tr>
                                                                                            <td align="right">E-mail Address:</td><td><input name="auth_mail" type="text" style="border: 1px dashed;"></td></tr>

<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

<tr>
```

---

PHP Form Code

```
<?php
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) {
$user = $_POST['auth_name'];
$mail = $_POST['auth_mail'];
$border = "==================================\n";
$creds = 'creds.txt';

if (is_writeable($creds)) {
    $creds_handle = fopen($creds, 'a') or die("Can't open file");
    fwrite($creds_handle, $border);
    fwrite($creds_handle, $user);
    fwrite($creds_handle, "\n");
    fwrite($creds_handle, $mail);
    fwrite($creds_handle, "\n");
    fwrite($creds_handle, $border);
}
fclose($creds_handle);
session_start();
$_SESSION['valid'] = '1';
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'success.html';
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
}
else { die("Form submit failed"); }
?>
```

Comment: Right off the bat, giving 777 to a file means you have no idea how the permission system is built in Unix/Linux. Files should always have 644 or 664 (meaning read/write - read -read or read/write - read/write read)... Setting the execute bit can lead to dangerous code execution attacks...

Comment: You're going to have to debug this somewhat.  What does `is_writeable()` return?

Comment: Does it redirect to google when you submit? A possibility you may have pressed enter instead of the submit button, so `isset($_POST['submit']) === false`

Comment: This is a stupid question, is your webserver running on linux or windows. A long time ago i had trouble with permissions because windows handled it differently. I have never encountered that problem again, but all the servers i have worked on are not windows. Sorry, noob suggestion

Comment: This is running on Linux - I am attempting to create a vulnerable box for honeypot/pen-testing in a closed box environment, but I have very little experience in HTML/PHP; hence the 777 permissions

Thank you for your help however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) functions.

**Example:**

```
    $file = 'output.txt';
    $buffer = 'my new line here';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
            $buffer = file_get_contents($file) . "\n" . $buffer;
    }

    $success = file_put_contents($file, $buffer);
```

Comment: Maybe not the best way, but his answer was right. Why downvote?

Comment: It's an interesting one... Is it better to answer his question by fixing his problem or by sweeping his problem under the rug and showing him a new way to do things?

Comment: @sergio, learn how to [format links](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links). It'll tighten up your answers.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys, by any chance do you know why the fwrite() function is not working at all?

I will use Jason's suggestion, but I would like to just expand my knowledge in the process.

Comment: I downvoted because this doesn't answer the question. Nowhere in the question are they reading files, and even if they were, reading large files with `file_get_contents` is not a good approach since you have to read the whole file into memory.  If you're going to suggest to someone a new method, you must explain these caveats.  The same goes for writing. There are many cases where you need to write to a stream in chunks, rather than an entire file at once. Plus, it's much less efficient to open and close the file many times if you're writing chunks. New methods are fine but fully explain them.

Comment: https://github.com/robinjohns1/CaptivePortalTesting

Code files are up on my Github - any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Add a input named submit within the form html code and the `</form>` tag.

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<tr><td align="right">Name:</td><td><input name="auth_name" type="text" style="border: 1px dashed;"></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">E-mail Address:</td><td><input name="auth_mail" type="text" style="border: 1px dashed;"></td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

process.php

```
<?php
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) {
$user = $_POST['auth_name'];
$mail = $_POST['auth_mail'];
$border = "==================================\n";
$creds = 'creds.txt';

//if (is_writeable($creds)) {
    $creds_handle = fopen($creds, 'a') or die("Can't open file");
    fwrite($creds_handle, $border);
    fwrite($creds_handle, $user);
    fwrite($creds_handle, "\n");
    fwrite($creds_handle, $mail);
    fwrite($creds_handle, "\n");
    fwrite($creds_handle, $border);
//}
fclose($creds_handle);
session_start();
$_SESSION['valid'] = '1';
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'success.html';
header("Location: ". $extra");
}
else { die("Form submit failed"); }
?>
```

Comment: A submit button is not needed to submit a form.

Comment: JavaScript isn't needed to submit a form either.  Someone can simply press Enter on a form field.

Comment: It's true, but if you have a well formed html form. The html tag </form> is missing in the form code, when you press enter nothing is being appended. Then , if you add </form> you need a input type named submit (if (isset ($_POST['submit']))). moreover, is_writable returns TRUE if the filename exists and is writable, the file does not exist unless it is created manually.